# Dictionary to table in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, html-table

I'm new to Django and so far have a difficult time learning it. Even though there is a lot of documentation I just can't put it together sometimes. Now I am stuck on putting a dictionary to a table... (yes I went through the tutorials)

Django 1.6 and python 2.7

view:

```
def panel(request):
 adlist = {}
 adlist['title'] = 'haas','paas'
 adlist['price'] = 12,50
 adlist['bid'] = 50,0
 adlist['seen'] = 23,11
 context = {'adlist' : adlist}
 return render(request, 'panel.html', context)enter code here
```

template(I tried alot of variations):

```
<table class="zebra">
<caption>Panel.</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>bid</th>
            <th>seen</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for ad in adlist %}
        <tr>

            <td>{{ ad.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ ad.price}}</td>
            <td>{{ ad.bid}}</td>
            <td>{{ ad.seen}}</td>

        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dictionary As Table In Django Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040037/dictionary-as-table-in-django-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a list of ads instead of a dictionary, for example:

```
def panel(request):
    adlist = [{'title': 'haas', 'price': 12.50, 'bid': 50.0, 'seen': 23.11}]
    return render(request, 'panel.html', {'adlist' : adlist})
```