# Convert Python dict into an interactive table in HTML

Tags: python, html, database, dictionary

I have a Python dict structure of some data, say `N` rows, each row containing some fields, `id`, `name` that contain free text and `property` that contains one of a few known keywords. 
I would like to turn this dict into an interactive HTML table, that is, I'd like to eventually upload this to my website and people would be able to sort by name, filter out according to the keywords of `property`, etc.

1. What's the easiest way to do that?

Now, one of the fields is an image address. I would also like this table to somehow contain the image as well (maybe as a thumbnail), and it would hyperlink to the orig. sized image. That is, my website would show some rows with the `id`, `name`, `property`, and also `image thumb` that will contain an image.

2. How can I do this?

I'm generally inclined to use Python, but other simple solutions will be welcome as well.

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way is to hire a web designer

Comment: I meant the easiest way without getting out of my room and without spending money other than the occasional snack.

Comment: If you want to do this you can start using Django and its templates. There are some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040037/dictionary-as-table-in-django-template). You just have to [search](https://www.google.ro/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=django%20dictionary%20to%20table)

Comment: @yoki so try to write some code and we'll help you

Comment: @Dex'ter Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in the comments, you have to use [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/). As an intro, Django comes with some templates.

From the docs, we know that:

> Being a web framework, Django needs a convenient way to generate HTML
>   dynamically. The most common approach relies on templates. A template
>   contains the static parts of the desired HTML output as well as some
>   special syntax describing how dynamic content will be inserted.

Now, supposing that you have a dictionary:

```
data = { 
    "test1": ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', ],
    "test2": ['val1', ],
    "test3": ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', ],
}
```

And you want it rendered in a HTML table, you'd do something like:

```
from django.template import Context, Template

data = {
    "test1": ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', ],
    "test2": ['val1', ],
    "test3": ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', ],
}

# we'll need to split the tests from the data

tests = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

columns = [data[test] for test in tests]

# get the length of the longest column
max_len = len(max(columns, key=len))

for col in columns:
    # padding the short columns with None
    col += [None,] * (max_len - len(col))

# Then rotate the structure...
rows = [[col[i] for col in columns] for i in range(max_len)]


dj_template ="""
<table>
{# tests #}
    <tr>
    {% for test in tests %}
        <th>{{ test }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{# data #}
{% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        {% for val in row %}
        <td>{{ val|default:'' }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Please provide some code next-time as your question it might be considered off-topic

Comment: Not being familiar with these extensions/frameworks, I wanted exactly that - to get a direction that I can get into. Thanks again.